# Is there a way to make this tolower( ... ) code faster?

Tags: c++, c++11

After looking around the web I came up with the following code to convert a char16_t* string to lower case.

Speed is rather important in my app, so I was wondering if there was a way of making this function even faster?

```
std::u16string ToLower(const char16_t* str)
{
  std::u16string data(str ? str : u"");
  std::u16string ldata;
  for (std::u16string::const_iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
  {
    ldata.push_back( std::use_facet<std::ctype<char16_t>>(std::locale()).tolower(*it) );
  }
  return ldata;
}
```

Part of me thinks that the "push_back( ... )" section itself is not the most efficient.

Maybe I could even not use a std::u16string at all and rather return a char16_t* and let the calling function delete that pointer.

```
// pseudo code - untested
// edited with suggestion from @Dietmar Kühl
char16_t* ToLower(const char16_t* str)
{
  if( NULL == str )
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  int l = strlen16( str );
  char16_t* ldata = new char16_t[ l + 1];
  auto const& ct = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char16_t>>(std::locale());
  for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i )
  {
    ldata[i] = ct.tolower(str[i]);
  }
  ldata[l] = u'\0'; 
  return ldata;
}
```

But then could "std::use_facet( ... )" be made faster still?

**Edit 1**

I ran some tests given the comments below

- strings of 1000 characters
- ran the test 1000 times.
- time is average.

Results are

- 11ms - my original code, (std::use_facet inside the loop)
- 10ms - std::use_facet outside the loop
- 10ms - std::use_facet outside the loop and using ldata.reserve(...)
- 4ms  - using char16_t* only, (the caller must delete)
- 5ms  - using char16_t* only but return std::u16string, (the function manages deletes).
- 4ms  - Multiple characters at once

So the char16_t* ToLower(const char16_t* str){ ... } function looks like a win.
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why not make `ldata` the same size as `data`? Or at least call `reserve(data.size())` on it?

Comment: If you want it to perform faster, do you have the option of replacing the characters in place instead of constructing a string object?

Comment: **Don't forget to null terminate ldata.**  That is before the `return ldata` statement, call `ldata[l] = '\0';`

Comment: Yes, thanks, (it's u'\0' btw), as mentioned, it is uncompilied pseudo code as an idea that could be maybe faster.

Comment: Did you try the version transforming multiple characters at once? I expect that to be another fairly large win. Also, did you use optimization when benchmarking the differences? The times quoted in relation of the use seem at least in order of magnitude off.

Comment: I think this is a typical question for a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @DietmarKühl, I added the multiple characters at once results also ~4/5ms. the tests above are without optimisation, with optimisations I get the same pattern in the results, (50% gain)

Comment: @FFMG: that's interesting. It points towards actual work being done for each character rather than a simple table look-up. I'd try the performance with a custom, table-driven `std::ctype<char16_t>` (initially just with a table which is just initialized somehow and if that works with one using a table initialized with results from the normal `std::ctype<char16_t>`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, you should get the facet outside the loop. That will probably make a huge difference, especially for not so great implementations of the locales library:

```
auto const& ct = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char16_t>>(std::locale());
for (std::u16string::const_iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
{
    ldata.push_back( ct.tolower(*it) );
}
```

There is also an overload of the member `tolower()` which converts an array of objects and calls the underlying `virtual` function just once. That is, you might want to use it as

```
std::u16string ToLower(const char16_t* str)
{
    if (!str) {
        return std::u16string();
    }
    std::u16string data(str);
    std::use_facet<std::ctype<char16_t>>(std::locale()).tolower(&data[0], &data[0] + data.size());
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Forgive my silliness :P  I was interested to know if there is any guarantee in Unicode that lowercase character will always be on the same code plane as original char?  If not, won't it corrupt the string if the lowercase char is in a higher code plane (so that it requires more than 1 utf-16 character to represent) and we are doing replacement in-place as you suggested?  (Although I don't think it happened in real life, just want to see if it is something enforced by standard)

Comment: @AdrianShum: if you have a question on an interface, ask it as a question not as a comment on another unrelated question!

Comment: I raised it here because the validity of the answer depends on such assumption (lowercase character always have same size as original one), while OP's original answer does not rely on such assumption (with the use of `push_back`).  So I think such assumption should be proven valid in order for you to suggest use of in-place replacement overload of `tolower()`

Comment: @AdrianShum: the use of `push_back()` makes exactly the same assumption as it also adds one output character (well UTF16 byte) per input character. The only change is improved performance. Discussion on the validity of the approach is an entirely independent question.